# Will not being able to access CMD affect my program?

Tags: c#, cmd

I am writing a piece of software that needs to launch another program. On the network I am using I am not an administrator and command prompt is blocked.
Will `Process.Start()` still work?

Comment: Why not just try it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will Process.Start() still work?

I can't see how an admin can prevent one process from *spawning* a *child process*.  It's an essential part of Windows.

For example:

- **Windows Explorer** runs in the user account of the currently logged-in user. In Windows 7+, selecting any folder with the mouse and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, causes a new **Windows Explorer** window to appear for the selected folder in a **new process**!  You can verify this in **Task Manager**

If you can do that on your computer in the selected user account, so too should your application.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking the command prompt will not stop Process.Start() from working.

How ever if an administrator has gone to the trouble to block the command prompt they may have implemented a group policy to only allow certain programs to be run.

See this link for details http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-use-local-group-policy-whitelist-certain-programs-in-windows-7

You may not be able to start any programs that are not on this "whitelist".

The easiest way to find out is to just try it yourself, but if you are able to run your own custom program that calls Process.Start(), the fact that your program runs, probably means the administrator has not set up such group policy.

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)